# How to authenticate domains on apache with google apps

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, google-apps, mod-auth-openidc

I want to authenticate some of my company's internal websites with Google Apps. We have been using openid based apache module `mod_auth_openid` and since it got [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) recently I started looking for alternatives and have found `mod_auth_openidc`. But I couldn't really get it to work as I didn't understand most parts of it (I have even tried to follow some articles ([article1](http://blog.boxever.com/tech/using-google-apps-openid-connect-with-apache), [article2](http://cloudavail.com/2014/06/07/apache-auth-oidc-google-apps-2/)) but that didn't help as it was not clear to me).

Is there any other solution/article that can help me do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first example in the README.md here:
https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/README.md
gives a good starting point:

```
OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCClientID <your-client-id-administered-through-the-google-api-console>
OIDCClientSecret <your-client-secret-administered-through-the-google-api-console>

OIDCRedirectURI https://www.example.com/example/redirect_uri
OIDCCryptoPassphrase <password>

OIDCScope "openid email profile"

<Location /example/>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user
    Require claim hd:<your-domain>
</Location>
```

Plain http will work, trailing slashes will work (if used consistently as in the example), no certificate needed just a fully qualified domain name, Debian packages work on Ubuntu 14.04.

The articles that you mention show also how to configure the Google side of things.

Comment: Just for the incredibly dense folks like me, you can choose whatever you want for `OIDCCryptoPassphrase`.  Also, another good reference is the configuration documentation for openidc:
https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/auth_openidc.conf

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just spent several hours configuring this.  I wound up using PingIdentity's OpenID Connect RP - https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc (open source - Apache license: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)

Works well, it's really picky to configure.  Some gotchas:

- Needs HTTPS - HTTP will not work correctly (despite what the docs say)
- All paths & domains must be set correctly & match
- Cookie & others paths must not have trailing slashes (/)
- ServerName must match cert
- Need a REAL cert (~$10)
- OIDCMetadataDir must be disabled to work with Google
- Binary distros don't work on Ubuntu, I compiled from scratch
- Compiling requires several dependencies & running autoconfig.sh
- Requires setup through Google's API Console, used Google+ APIs

In other words, it's not tolerant of sloppy configs that might work OK with vanilla Apache.  But, in the end, it works great.  BTW, there is new Google group for this module here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mod_auth_openidc

Other solutions (untested) from my original answer

- Odin: http://www.ginzametrics.com/blog/announcing-odin-authenticator/
- Google Apps SSO: https://github.com/epotocko/apache-google-apps-sso (hasn't been updated in a while)

P.S. Deleted a previous answer in order to merge two Stack accounts....

Comment: I have tried Odin and it is using openid :( Do let me know if anything works for you.

Comment: see my last edit.  OpenID works, but it needs a modern implementation.  mod_auth_openidc is very, very new and seems to work great.  I have it currently running, no issues so far.  We'll see if it holds up over the next few days.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already compiled and installed mod_auth_openidc on Ubuntu server and I'm only stuck at configuration, can you please share/explain your configuration? That would be awesome.

Comment: Have you configured your Google APIs?   What errors are you getting in the logs and browser?

Comment: Note that by default OIDCMetadataDir is enabled, you have to find it and disable it.  I removed all the defaults from the config file and cut/pasted the sample config from GitHub.  I also added a full domain name with OIDCCookieDomain.

Comment: Thanks @ckm for all your advice and help. I was able to set this up.